# How to remove properties from one item and add to another with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Guys! I have a menu with few links, and when i click on one of them i want to show horizontal line, like on screenshot below.[image]

I've tried to use this script, but now css properties applies to all of the links. What should i do to remove propertie from inactive link, and apply it to one, that i clicked? Thank you!

```
$('.main-menu-link-container').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.main-menu-link-line').css({"width": "6.11em", "marginRight": "2.36em"});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some context (your current HTML markup) was missing so it was hard to perfectly address your exact issue. Anyway, your main concern was how to address the element that fired the click event.

Your events seem attached to the parent menu element, which is a good coding habit considering Events are better handled using **delegation** in order to handle current or future, dynamic child elements.

#### The problem

jQuery's `$(this)` is the somewhat *"equivalent"* of `Event.currentTarget` in *vanilla* JavaScript. When using **direct events** like `$("targetSelector").on("eventName", fn)` the `this` inside the callback function refers directly to any element matching the "targetSelector". In your case the parent element.
`.find("childSelector")` returns a **collection** of child Elements,  `.css()` *will* apply the new styles to **every** such child element in the collection.

#### The solution: *proper* event delegation

In a jQuery-syntax use [Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) by providing a second argument to the `.on("eventName", "dynamicChildSelector")` and inside the function use `$(this)` - which will be the actual clicked child:

```js
// "Static delegated parent"     "EventName", "dynamicChild"
$('.main-menu-link-container').on("click", ".menu-link", function(evt) {

  const $menu = $(evt.delegateTarget); // The '.main-menu-link-container' parent
  const $links = $menu.find(".menu-link"); // All the children links
  const $link = $(this); // or: $(evt.currentTarget) The clicked ".menu-link" element 
  
  $links.removeClass("is-active"); // remove from all children
  $link.addClass("is-active");     // add to the clicked one
  
});
```

```css
* {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.main-menu-link-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.menu-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid white 3px;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-link::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0rem;
  height: 0.3rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.menu-link.is-active::before {
  width: 6rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu-link-container">
  <div class="menu-link">Link 1</div>
  <div class="menu-link">Link 2</div>
  <div class="menu-link">Link 3</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, instead of changing the styles directly using JS (bad practice since hard to maintain) use the `.[add/remove/toggle]Class()` methods - and set the styles in your Stylesheet - where due.

#### Event delegation in JavaScript

For comparison, here's the same approach to event delegation in pure JavaScript, without the overhead of a library like jQuery:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);

// Task: Menu active items

const handleActiveMenuItem = (evt) => {
  const elLink = evt.target.closest(".menu-link"); // The clicked element's closest selector / or self
  if (!elLink) return; // Do nothing, no link clicked
  const elMenu = evt.currentTarget; // The event-bound element
  const elsLinks = els(".menu-link", elMenu);
  
  elsLinks.forEach(elLink => elLink.classList.remove("is-active")); // remove from all children
  elLink.classList.add("is-active"); // add to the clicked one
};

els(".main-menu-link-container").forEach(elMenu => {
  elMenu.addEventListener("click", handleActiveMenuItem);
});
```

```css
* {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.main-menu-link-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.menu-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid white 3px;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-link::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0rem;
  height: 0.3rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.menu-link.is-active::before {
  width: 6rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu-link-container">
  <div class="menu-link">Link 1</div>
  <div class="menu-link">Link 2</div>
  <div class="menu-link">Link 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes please. As you can see I made a correction and it's actually taking into account your advise. But it was convoluted because I didn't consider that `closest` was going to include also the starting node. Feel free to edit. Right now is broken because I left it unfinished.. I'll correct it tomorrow if I won't find edits

Comment: Well your answer is much better indeed. You also used $ prefix convention for variables holding jQuery objects (that I don't usually in the rare cases I use jQuery). Thanks for your support and your time. I learnt to face someone pointing me in a different direction without reacting unproperly :D and it was interesting to read your edited answer of course. I think we had a different kind of confrontation months ago when I still reacted in different ways